# Are fewer columns better for frequent writing? mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an application that lets users vote videos up or down. Currently, I have the upvotes/downvotes in the videos table, because I couldn't think of a reason why not (they're only integers). But it's a case where every single user might cause a write to the table when they vote, and that's making me think twice.

The only thing I can think of is that, possibly, the table lock that MSQL applies when writing could slow down reads. Would it be more efficient to move the votes to their own small, 3-column table?

(I'm sure MYSQL is powerful enough either way unless traffic gets very heavy, but I like to do things right the first time.)

Comment: There are other factors that might affect this - presence or otherwise of indexes that might need updating, or the exact engine in use (InnoDB uses row-level locking). You'd have to profile it to get a definitive answer, but probably it'll make little difference. Worry about it when (if) it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, like most mysql performance questions, the answer is really 'it depends'. You're right to want to avoid excessive locking which might block a read, and putting the votes in their own table might help, or it might just be a waste of time and extra complexity. The biggest variable in my mind is the transaction size - if updating that 'vote' field is part of a large transaction, then it's more likely to hold that lock and block further writes. If votes are autocommitted, then you probably don't have much to worry about.

Worst case scenario, if things really get dicey and you have to deal with millions of votes a second, you could move the vote counter out into a MEMORY table and sync it with your on-disk table every 60 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the writes will affect your reads depends on your isolation level. If you use the READ-COMMITED isolation level then your reads will use snapshot consistency but not require a lock; however if you make the same request multiple times in one transaction it could have different results. If you use REPEATABLE-READ isolation level then your reads will acquire a lock but they will also guarantee that rerunning the same query will give the same results. (There are other isolation levels than these two, which you can read up on on the MySQL website).

I would advise that you use the lowest isolation level which you can and still get whatever consistency you need. If you can get by with READ-COMMITED isolation then use that and you won't have to worry about READ-WRITE contention.

Everything depends on your use case, but it should be OK to put the columns on the same table. One case where I would separate them is if you have large numbers of writes to those columns as well as large numbers of different writes to other columns on the table and they are all performed within medium to large transactions. In that case I would split them out.